# What happens with the old content when I use ajax and jquery's $.get() to render new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dashboard feature on my website where I'm using ajax and jquery to render partial content. That is I have a sidebar and when the user clicks one of the items the content of the page changes but not the sidebar, navbar, footer and you get the point.

But what happens to the content thats not displayed anymore? Is it still there in the background slowing down my page? Should I avoid alternating between large amounts of content in this manner?

Comment: *"Should I avoid alternating between large amounts of content in this manner"* we can't answer that, we don't know what your app does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. Let's take a simple example:

```js
$(function () {
  $("aside nav a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
<main>
  <h1></h1>
  <div id="content"></div>
</main>
```

The above code, scraps everything inside the `#content` div and loads fresh content from AJAX. The old content **is not there** anywhere in the page. Most of the implementations are similar to this.

Comment: So since I'm using `$('.dashboard.content').html(newContent)` the old content is scrapped. Thanks!

Comment: @vhflat Yes buddy, you are right. Glad that it solved.